# Getting the sAMAccountName for all users in a AD Group

Tags: go, ldap, ldap-query

I've encountered some problems that seems like there should be a better solution to my problem?

In Go:

I succeed in retrieving the CN from a group (also able to traverse nested groups)
Looping each of the users:
I though that I could use the CN in getting the "sAMAccountName" for that user

- Try 1: From l.Search I get response "Example1" below - with a "\" before the "," - Using this gives an exception.
- Try 2: Removing the "\" (Example 2) - Returns with 0 entries
- Try 3: Removing the "," (in the name) -  Returns with 0 entries
- Try 4: Modifying the string to add """ around name - Returns with 0 entries
- Try 5: Similar tries with using ldap.EscapeFilter() all fail with exception or 0 entries in reply.

(userAccountControl - to remove disabled users - also tested without it)

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/ldap.v2"
)
 
//First search for members in group
    sr, err := l.Search(&ldap.SearchRequest{
        BaseDN: "dc=ad,dc=some",
        Scope:      2, // subtree
        Filter:     "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=TheGroup)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))",
        Attributes: []string{"member", "cn", "dn"},
    })
 
//Looping through the users from the reply
 
Example1: user="CN=Some\, Name,OU=ABCD,OU=UsersInternal,OU=Users,OU=DEFG,OU=HIJ,DC=ad,DC=some"
Example2: user="CN=Some, Name,OU=ABCD,OU=UsersInternal,OU=Users,OU=DEFG,OU=HIJ,DC=ad,DC=some"
Example3: user=\"CN="Some, Name\",OU=ABCD,OU=UsersInternal,OU=Users,OU=DEFG,OU=HIJ,DC=ad,DC=some"
Example4: user="CN='Some, Name',OU=ABCD,OU=UsersInternal,OU=Users,OU=DEFG,OU=HIJ,DC=ad,DC=some"
 
 
filter:=fmt.Sprintf("(%s)", user)
 
    result, err := l.Search(&ldap.SearchRequest{
        BaseDN:     "dc=ad,dc=some",
        Scope:      2, // subtree
        Filter:     filter,
        Attributes: []string{"sAMAccountName"},
    })
```

Workaround w problems:

```
user = "Some Name"
filter := fmt.Sprintf("(&(anr=%s)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))", user)
```

Current workaround is to use anr - but then I fail to combine the search with the group that I initially searched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should work (and even faster) to get directly a given object, since you already have user's DN. I would use user's DN as base DN (without any escaping) and set scope as base. Unfortunately I don't have an AD with commas in CNs to run a test.

BTW. `userAccountControl` attribute is defined on user objects, not groups. If you wish to filter that way, it might actually be easier to resolve group name to a DN and then issue a single search for getting all the users, i.e.:

1. Use filter `(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=TheGroup))` with scope subtree and attributes `dn`,
2. Use filter `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(memberOf=TheGroupDN))` with scope subtree and attribute `sAMAccountName`.

This way you would issue just two queries instead of querying each user separately.

Comment: Thanks!

When I tested this before I used the (memberOf=TheGroup) not the GroupDN - Now it works!
Now I only need to handle a few group names beginning with a "#"... "//#" gives an exception...

Comment: struggling on...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309123/ldap-search-for-all-members-using-a-group-with-in-the-name